# Avoid writing the password of a Gmail account in my code

Tags: email, smtp, swiftmailer

I want to use a Gmail email to work as an SMTP server.

I don't want to write the password for the email server in my code, is  possible another alternative?

Besides, my customer doesn't want to tell me the password of his Gmail email.

So what should I do to use the Gmail email as a SMTP server in my case?

Comment: Why couldn't you make it a variable defined in a config file? You could also use the OAuth API.

Comment: @Benjamin thanks, written in the code or in a config file, is both cases written in the project

Comment: But, what I mean is have your users add the email to the configuration file.

Comment: @ziiweb Did you see the answer in your Gmail-API-Question? It should solve the problem!